# how to get xml parse value in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here,I want to get (loop)the number of Latitude & Longitude from response to var data,data1.
Help me to solve this ...

### Response:

```
{"Last30PointsDataJSon":[{"Latitude":11.766470,"Longitude":77.884158,"Speed":11.00,"PositionTime":"16/Mar/2019 04:32:32 PM","PositionType":"GPS","Direction":"NorthWest","ACC":"Off","Battery":"100%","GSMStrength":"Strong Signal","PowerStatus":"Power Connected"},{"Latitude":11.766087,"Longitude":77.884393,"Speed":35.00,"PositionTime":"16/Mar/2019 04:32:22 PM","PositionType":"GPS","Direction":"NorthWest","ACC":"Off","Battery":"100%","GSMStrength":"Strong Signal","PowerStatus":"Power Connected"},{"Latitude":11.765148,"Longitude":77.884998,"Speed":45.00,"PositionTime":"16/Mar/2019 04:32:12 PM","PositionType":"GPS","Direction":"NorthWest","ACC":"Off","Battery":"100%","GSMStrength":"Strong Signal","PowerStatus":"Power Connected"}]}
```

```js
var txt = '<?php echo $response;?>' //here,I got the Json response (above response)
var parser, xmlDoc;
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
var data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Latitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var data1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Longitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log(data,',',data1);
var locations=[
[data,data1]
];
```

Comment: The response text appears to be JSON, not XML. There's no magic tool to turn JSON into XML. It's possible to create some sort of transformation but that doesn't make much sense. You can simply treat the response data as a JavaScript object and extract the values you want directly.

Comment: Ya,thanks for your guidance Pointy...I will try the xml - Json format..:)